# How can I share only one page of a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-docs

**Example:**

I have a document that I use together with my team. There is one page I want to share with one of our clients but only this page. He should not be able to see the other pages of the document.

Comment: You might be able to do something with Google Sites, but I don't know enough about it to offer a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. You need separate documents.

With Sheets, you could have one (public) sheet pulling in data from a different (private) sheet, but such a thing isn't possible with Docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest duplicating the document, deleting the unwanted pages, and sending the revised document to your client.  It should be noted that changes to one document will not be reflected on the other document.